# Tensorflow: saving and resoring session - multiple variables

Tags: python, tensorflow

Given the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    var = tf.Variable(42, name='var')
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    tf.train.export_meta_graph('file.meta')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('file.meta')
    print sess.run(var)
```

I get an error at the line `saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('file.meta')` saying `ValueError: At least two variables have the same name: var`.

How can I get around this? Is there anyway to *overwrite* the compute graph when importing a metagraph?

**EDIT:**

I have arrived at the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

file_name = "./file"

with tf.Session() as sess:
    var = tf.Variable(42, name='my_var')
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(sess,file_name)
    saver.export_meta_graph(file_name + '.meta')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(file_name + '.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, file_name)
    print(sess.run(var))

    # new code that fails:
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(sess,file_name)
    saver.export_meta_graph(file_name + '.meta')
```

This prints the correct value for `var`, but when I come to save the graph a second time, I get the same original error: `ValueError: At least two variables have the same name: var`

Comment: Hey @Tom, are you satisfied with my answer?

Comment: Hey @martianwars , see my edit

Comment: Hey @martianwars edited to include `reset_default_graph`

Comment: @martianwars , isn't that what `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` does?

Comment: Mostly NaN, sometimes a random float

Comment: @martianwars , results in: `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value var_1`

Comment: I don't know what value I would be assigning to it

Comment: Hey, what's the update on this @Tom?

Comment: Still stuck at that same spot. Assigment as you said didn't seem to help. If I add graph resets in various places I get other errors

Comment: Hey @Tom, see the updated answer

Comment: Sorry for the wrong advice given earlier. I was on a mobile phone and it's difficult without the docs and a text editor in front of you :)

Answer (score 7):

In this case you are loading the variable in the default graph where you already have the variable defined. Hence
you will need to reset the TensorFlow graph before importing it.

Do this using `tf.reset_default_graph()`. before you import. Have a look at the "Import within the default graph" section under [Exporting and Importing a MetaGraph](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/meta_graph/).

Of course, you will have to redefine the variable `var` using `tf.get_variable()`. Try out this code,

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    var = tf.Variable(42, name='var')
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    tf.train.export_meta_graph('file.meta')
tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('file.meta')
    var = tf.global_variables()[0]
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    print sess.run(var)
```

---

The reason your intermediate code wasn't working was that `tf.get_variable()` was creating a new variable which was being randomly initialized. Make sure you first do `tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()` first.
Have a look at [Understanding `tf.get_variable()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/variable_scope/#understanding_tfget_variable).

Unfortunately, your variable created using `tf.Variable()` cannot be reused with `tf.get_variable()` directly. Have a look at this [comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1325#issuecomment-190428758) and this [comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1325#issuecomment-259040409) to know exactly why. Hence you will need to use `tf.get_variable()` to *create* the variable if you wish to reuse it in the future.